# Share extension without UI

Tags: ios, swift, share-extension

I've created a Share extension that will save a file URL to user default. The extension comes with a UI with Post and Cancel button. How can I remove this (the UI) so that when I press my share extension, it will straight away call the didSelectPost?

I'm using Swift 3 and building for iPhone

Comment: Not sure if you really mean Swift 3 as in the 2016 version of swift. Make sure it is compatible with Xcode 14.1 https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=jd9wcyov

Answer (score 1):

The template uses a SLComposeServiceViewController. Use a plain view controller instead. The entire interface, including providing a way to dismiss the view controller, will then be up to you.

(However, I can't help wondering whether what you really want might not be an Action extension.)

Comment: I'm using it to share a file which I have converted into Data before set it in user default for use in my host app.